# seperate strings in column based on count of delimiters

Tags: r

I am trying to split 1st column based on delimiter("_") in df.

```
country_city_gender_age_name_state =c("US_Dallas_Male_23_hanes_TX","US_LosAngeles_CA",
"US_Atlanta_Female_jenny_GA","US_Orlando_kane_FL")

df = data.frame(country_city_gender_age_name_state)
```

Ist string before 1st delimiter , 2nd string after 1st delimiter and last string before last delimiter are contant
According to above statement
in row_1 : All the strings splitted based on delimiter and no.of delimiters are 5
      row_2 : delimiter 2,3,4 are missing ,so values are empty and no.of delimiters are 2
      row_3 : delimiter 3 is missing ,so values are empty and no.of delimiters are 4
      row_4 : delimiter 2,3 are missing ,so values are empty and no.of delimiters are 3

I have tried with below code.

```
df$country<- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$country_city_gender_age_name_state),"_"), "[",1)
df$city<- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$country_city_gender_age_name_state),"_"), "[",2)
df$gender<- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$country_city_gender_age_name_state),"_"), "[",3)
df$age<- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$country_city_gender_age_name_state),"_"), "[",4)
df$name<- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$country_city_gender_age_name_state),"_"), "[",5)
df$state<- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$country_city_gender_age_name_state), "_"), tail, 1)
```

Desired output Data frame will be

```
country = c("US","US","US","US")
city = c("Dallas","LosAngeles","Atlanta","Orlando")
gender = c("Male","","Femal","")
age = c("23","","","")
name = c("hanes","","Jenny","kane")
state = c("TX","CA","GA","FL")

out_df = data.frame(country_city_gender_age_name_state,country,city,gender,age,name,state)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: thats hard to do. How to tell the computer LosAngeles is not a name like "Jenny".

Comment: possible starting position: `library(tidyverse);df$country_city_gender_age_name_state %>% map(~str_split(.,"_") %>% unlist %>% trimws)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, although it might be hard to generalize. It works in case country, city and state are never missing, gender is always "Female" or "Male", and the only digits in the string relate to the desired "age" variable. Some lines could of course be adapted in case that's necessary, and also, perhaps some of these lines could be a little shortened. Anyway, does this help?

```
df = data.frame(country_city_gender_age_name_state, stringsAsFactors = F)

df$country <- sapply(strsplit(df$country_city_gender_age_name_state, "_"), "[[", 1)
df$city <- sapply(strsplit(df$country_city_gender_age_name_state, "_"), "[[", 2)
df$state <-  sapply(strsplit(df$country_city_gender_age_name_state, "_"), tail, 1)
df$gender <- ifelse(grepl("Female", df$country_city_gender_age_name_state), "Female", ifelse(grepl("Male", df$country_city_gender_age_name_state), "Male", NA))


df$age <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df$country_city_gender_age_name_state))                   

df$name <- sapply(strsplit(df$country_city_gender_age_name_state, "_"), tail, 2)[1,]
df$name <- ifelse(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) df[x,"name", drop = FALSE] %in%  df[x,2:6]), NA, df$name)

> df[,c(1:3,5:7,4)]
  country_city_gender_age_name_state country       city gender age  name state
1         US_Dallas_Male_23_hanes_TX      US     Dallas   Male  23 hanes    TX
2                   US_LosAngeles_CA      US LosAngeles   <NA>  NA  <NA>    CA
3         US_Atlanta_Female_jenny_GA      US    Atlanta Female  NA jenny    GA
4                 US_Orlando_kane_FL      US    Orlando   <NA>  NA  kane    FL
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide a beautiful solution, but this one must work. You can always find lists of states, countries and cities so just make ifelse conditions to compare whether a value is in one of the lists. For names of states, you can deal with a regEx condition for 2 letters or use a list. The value that cannot be found in the lists or matched by regEx must be name.

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt$number_of_entry <- rep(1:nrow(dt))
new_dt <- dt %>% mutate(country_city_gender_age_name_state =
```

strsplit(as.character(country_city_gender_age_name_state), "_")) %>% 
unnest(country_city_gender_age_name_state)

```
output <- data.frame(id = 1:nrow(dt),
                     country = rep(NA, nrow(dt)),
                     gender = rep(NA, nrow(dt)),
                     age = rep(NA, nrow(dt)),
                     name = rep(NA, nrow(dt)),
                     state = rep(NA, nrow(dt)))

number_of_entry = 1
for (i in nrow(new_dt)) {
  while (number_of_entry == new_dt$number_of_entry) {

    if (new_dt$country_city_gender_age_name_state[i] %in% list_of_countries) {
      output[number_of_entry,]$country = new_dt$country_city_gender_age_name_state[i]}
    else {

      if (new_dt$country_city_gender_age_name_state[i] %in% c("Female", "Male")) {
        output[number_of_entry,]$gender = new_dt$country_city_gender_age_name_state[i]}
      else {

        if (new_dt$country_city_gender_age_name_state[i] %in% list_of_cities) {
          output[number_of_entry,]$city = new_dt$country_city_gender_age_name_state[i]}
        else {
          if(grepl("\\d*", new_dt$country_city_gender_age_name_state[i])) {
            output[number_of_entry,]$age = new_dt$country_city_gender_age_name_state[i]}
          else {
            if (new_dt$country_city_gender_age_name_state[i] %in% list_of_states) {
              output[number_of_entry,]$state = new_dt$country_city_gender_age_name_state[i]}
            else {
              output[number_of_entry,]$name = new_dt$country_city_gender_age_name_state[i]}
            }
          }
         }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks KAtin, the above data is sample data and we can not consider gender column  as constant ,it may be a zip code column

Comment: Just use regex to filter it.